# JavaScript input keyUp event Listener Promise return only for first time, after every keyUp promise value is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, dom-events, es6-promise

Demo in this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-syxlxy?file=index.js)

I have one input search box. I am adding event listener of `keyUp` to input search box. I am calling below function from my JavaScript file to add event-listener inside input box with promise.

```
export function onSearch(element) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       element.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
          resolve(event.target.value);
       });
   });
}
```

If you see Attached demo link of stackblitz, this function `onSearch()` is part of `Utilities/search.js` file. and I am calling this function from index.js file like below:

```
let searchBar = document.getElementById('serachBar');
let searchTerm = onSearch(searchBar);
searchTerm.then(e => console.log('fire', e));
```

Now, My question is when keyUp event occurs at search input, then `onSearch()` function gets called, and `onSearch()` is returning promise. But I am getting value of promise resolve for first time only and `searchTerm.then(e => console.log('fire',e))` fires for first key stroke event, after every keystroke event this searchTerm function is not called by `onSeach()` promise. Why? Can You spot whats going on wrong here?

For Demo you can check out attached stackbliz link to see how its not working.

Comment: There's no need for Promise gymnastics here; just add the event listener and put inside the callback what you want to happen: `searchBar.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log('fire', e.target.value);
});` The promise only resolves once, when `onSearch(searchBar);` is called initially.

Comment: I want to seperate out event listner part to another function , and also i am applying debouncing with keyup event too. After some debounce time, I want to return this value to `index.js` file. thats why I am using promise. If you see in demo in `Utilities/search.js` file, I also implemented debounce too. How can I return value back to index.js file after some debounce time ? Thank you .@ChrisG

Answer (score 1):

Here's what `onSearch` needs to look like:

```
export function onSearch(element, cb) {
  element.addEventListener('input', debounce(cb));
}
```

(this function should probably be named differently, given that it's just a convenience function that adds an `input` event listener with debounce and doesn't relate to searching)

In index.js, you do

```
onSearch(searchBar, function(e) {
  console.log('fire', e.target.value);
});
```

---

**Edit:**
based on the requirement to be able to write

```
onSearch(searchBar).then(function(e) {
  console.log('fire', e.target.value);
});
```

here's an alternate solution:

```
export function onSearch(element) {
  let cb;
  element.addEventListener('input', e => cb(e));
  return {
    then: fn => (cb = debounce(fn))
  };
}
```

Still no Promise, but it's simply the wrong tool for this job, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-h4zzbb?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you for solution, But Can I do same using promise, without callback function? is it posible ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I've added another solution (still no Promise though)